# Filtering table data without a search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table with item names and dates at the side of them.  I then have another table that i need to add all the objects with a certain date on them adding into this from the table. For example i want to take all the objects with the date 03/08/13 from this table and add them to another array. Is this even possible the only way i could think of is to have a similar method to the search bar filter method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The table above has two separate NSMutableArrays for the labels so i would need to have two filter arrays i think.

[image]

Comment: May I ask what you're planning on doing with the new array created? With regards to how you're storing your data btw, you might not need two arrays (1 for each label). 1 practice is to create an `NSDictionary` object and assign data to keys which correspond to different elements of your cell. That way, you only have a single object to associate to any given cell. Let me know if you're interested and I can detail it in a proper answer.

Comment: its basically a task app so i want to create an array on the main view controller to show all the tasks due on that day ? i hadn't considered using an NSDictionary for the labels would that help with filtering ?

Comment: In my opinion yes it would make it a simpler task as you'd only need to filter 1 array instead of 2. I'll submit an answer with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use 2 arrays: 1 for each label. Instead, you can use an `NSDictionary` object and assign data to keys which correspond to different elements of your cell. After that, to do your date filtering, you can do the following:

```
// Create current calendar
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Setup date components from date
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

// Set date components
[dateComponents setHour:0];
[dateComponents setMinute:0];
[dateComponents setSecond:0];
NSDate *startOfDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
[dateComponents setHour:23];
[dateComponents setMinute:59];
[dateComponents setSecond:59];
NSDate *endOfDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

// Create predicate to filter your date
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(cellDate > %@) AND (cellDate < %@)",startOfDate, endOfDate];

NSArray *filteredArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

You should make sure that you store your cell dates as `NSDate`'s in each `NSDictionary` object. Also, the reason you need to use all that setup above is because if you simply used a `@"cellDate == @filterDate"` predicate, it won't work because of the time factor (unless you happen to know and/or have explicitly specified the exact time of the dates saved).

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks :) The NSDictionary method of populating the table is much more effective

Answer (score 0):

Having two separate arrays is the best solution. If you're using Core Data you can simply set a filter predicate on `NSFetchedResultsController`; otherwise you can simply add the objects from your unfiltered array to your filtered array. Let me know which approach you'd use and if you have any questions about either.